# Why does this example miss one Future result?

Tags: scala, future

I am new to Scala Future. Below is an example from programming scala book (Dean & Alex 2nd Edition page 41 - A Taste of Futures). I am trying to understand how does future work.

From my understanding, the following programming should run dowork function 5 times (dowork(1), dowork(2), dowork(3), dowork(4) and dowork(5), 5 jobs in total).

But when I run it in Eclipse (Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK Build id: 4.0.0-vfinal-20150119-1023-Typesafe) on a Mac , from the output (below) it seems it only did 4 times (dowork(1), dowork(2), dowork(3) and dowork(4)).

I don't know what's wrong with it? Can you explain what happen?

```
package com.future.test

import java.sql.Timestamp
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object TestFutures {

  def sleep(millis: Long) = {
    Thread.sleep(millis)
  }

  // Busy Work:)
  def dowork(index: Int) = {
    val time = (math.random * 1000).toLong
    sleep(time)
    println()
    println(s"index: $index " +  new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) + s" time used: $time.")
    index
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    (1 to 5) foreach {
      index =>
        val future =
          Future {
            dowork(index)
          }
        future onSuccess {
          case answer: Int => println(s"Success! returned: $answer.")
        }
        future onFailure {
          case th: Throwable => println(s"Failed! returned: $th.")
        }
    }

    sleep(1000)
    println("done.")

  }

}
```

Here it is the output:

index: 1 2015-04-11 23:06:01.273 time used: 272.
Success! returned: 1.

index: 3 2015-04-11 23:06:01.45 time used: 451.
Success! returned: 3.

index: 4 2015-04-11 23:06:01.461 time used: 462.
Success! returned: 4.

index: 2 2015-04-11 23:06:01.773 time used: 777.
Success! returned: 2.

done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without running it, I can almost guarantee the problem is that you are only sleeping for 1000 millis instead of awaiting all futures to complete and/or waiting using `io.StdIn.readLine("Press ENTER to continue...")`.

You would probably see this if you add a `println` before `sleep`, also.